# Deploy an application on the Apple Store for employees only

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I want to know if it's possible to put an application, on the apple store, that only the company employees can log into.

I know that I can distribute the application in-house only, but my question is about putting an app that won't be accessible to the general user, even if he downloads it, could cause any problems with the validation process ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And yes, it would likely get rejected.

Comment: the company doesn't want to pay for an enterprise program, they prefer using their developer account.

Comment: @Wain  I knew it'll probably get rejected, but how can banks put their apps on the store even it's accessible only to their clients ? Isn't it the same principle ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Apple Enterprise Developer Program, you'll be given a certificate with which you can install it to multiple devices.

For restricted installation, only for Employees, you might use

- Third party MDM
- Develop your own server (not complex) with Over-The-Air installation. That is not difficult at all, you just need secure web server (dropbox e.g), special manifest file for your app, and special link in html. When a user taps on it, the app will be installed. Note: you can implement user authorisation/authentication before you show that link.

That could be your solution.

UPDATE

You can use over-the-air installation with developer program as well. You don't necessarily need enterprise program.

Comment: thanks, but I have a question about how the banks can publish their applications on the store. It's the same principle, the app is also restricted to  the banks' clients only.

Comment: question, how can I use over-the-air installation with the developer program ? Does it work the same way ?

Comment: over-the-installation works the same way as for enterprise, previously test flight site worked similar. Banks might use MDM or/with  Volume Purchase Program (VPP).

Answer (score 1):

Probably that's what you looking for
http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

or you can distribute your application using one of the many third‑party services:
https://www.apperian.com/ 
http://ubertesters.com/
http://hockeyapp.net/
https://www.installrapp.com/
etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you prevent other users from using your app.
I'm pretty sure that Apple won't like it.